# I'm arriving to the US by air, but departing via land. How do I end form I-94 now that it is only electronic?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, esta, i-94

I need to end my visa waiver period when leaving States to Canada so that I don't exceed the period of 90 days. But form I-94 is no longer a physical card, it's only online.

How do I know or ensure that it will be terminated and will not continue counting the days once I leave to Canada?

Answer (score 11):

I actually just found what I was looking for. According to [US CBP at I94 FAQ](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/request.html):

> Q: *If I arrive via air but leave via land - thus I dont have paper
> form I-94 - how to report departure?*
>
> A: If you have a paper form I-94 and depart by land, you can turn the
> form into Canadian Border Services Agency (CBSA) upon entry into
> Canada or to CBP at the port of entry prior to entering Mexico.
>
> If you received an electronic I-94 upon arrival by air or sea and depart via land, your departure may not be recorded accurately. A departure will
> be recorded if you depart via land and re-enter the United States
> prior to the expiration date stamped in your passport.
>
> If you are not
> a resident of Canada or Mexico and you receive an electronic I-94 and
> depart via land, but do not re-enter the United States prior to the
> expiration date stamped on your passport, you may want to travel with
> evidence of your departure into Canada or Mexico. Evidence of
> departure can include, but is not limited to, entry stamps in a
> passport, transportation tickets, pay stubs and/or other receipts. A
> traveler can request an entry stamp from CBSA when entering Canada or
> from the InstitutoNacional de Migracion (INM) when entering Mexico.

Hope this helps everybody worried about it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to worry, as it's all done electronically and automatically now, so you don't need to do anything yourself.

From the CBP page [I-94 Goes Electronic](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/i-94-instructions):

> Foreign visitors to the U.S. arriving via air or sea no longer need to
>   complete paper Customs and Border Protection Form I-94 or I-94W. Those
>   who need to prove their legal-visitor status—to employers,
>   schools/universities or government agencies—can access their CBP
>   arrival/departure record information online.

However if you arrived by land, you may still need to hand over your paper one if you received one:

> Upon exiting the U.S., travelers previously issued a paper Form I-94
>   should surrender it to the commercial carrier or to CBP upon
>   departure. Otherwise, CBP will record the departure electronically via
>   manifest information provided by the carrier or by CBP.

Comment: What does one do if they arrive by air, but leave by land?

Comment: It's taken care of electronically.  Even when I last arrived by land it was electronic.  I guess it's a gradual move towards digitizing the whole process.

Comment: So they automatically stop my visa waiver day count (Iam allowed only 90 days in USA on that) once I leave States?

Comment: @mariana if it was less than 90 days, and you visit Canada or Mexico, it keeps counting. But this is only a problem if you're coming back into the USA on the same trip.  We have several other questions on that on the site if you're interested - search for 90 days esta.

Answer (score -4):

If Arriving by land or sea and departing via air....

You will receive a paper I-94.  However, when departing via air, your airline will ELECTRONICALLY record your departure.  It might be a good idea to keep a boarding record and the paper I-94 in a safe place.

If Arriving by Air and departing via land or sea...

You will NOT receive a paper I-94.  You will still need to prove to CBP you departed.  So what you need to do on exit is ask CBSA or Mexican border authorities to stamp your passport, even if not normally done to prove your exit from the United States.  This along with travel documentation will prove your exit from the US.

Also, CBP will advise you of your requirements on exit.  They always ask how and when you'll be leaving and they would also be able to advise you of your legal requirements on entry.

Comment: Please don't copy and paste without attribution, especially when the information has already been given in another answer.