# Do CBSA officials "accept" electronic I94s for transmission to the CBP?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, i-94

I'm considering flying to New York, spending a week and then continuing to Montreal by Train before flying home to Europe.

I've been trying to find out whether Amtrak (the US train operator) records passport info to the CBP (US border agency) so they can establish my departure (airlines do this), without getting any useful answer.

However, I also know, having read it on the CBP Website, that paper I-94W forms (the ones you get when entering by land) can be handed in to CBSA (Canadian border agency) officials, who will pass on the data to the CBP.

**My question is**: can I similarly hand in a printout of the electronic I94 record (what you receive when entering the US by air) to CBSA officials, or do they only "accept" the old paper version?

If all else Fails, the last Resort is sending my Train ticket, passport copy with Canadian entry stamp, and electronic I94 printout along with an explanation letter to a dedicated address in Ohio. However, I'd really prefer it if there's any other means, either Amtrak passing on my data to the CBP, or the CBSA taking my electronic I94 printout and passing it on.

Comment: You can request a paper I-94 form on arrival for this express purpose if you enter at an airport, though you should expect this to add perhaps 15 minutes or so to your time at immigration.

Comment: I see, that's nice! Do you happen to know, though, if CBSA officers would accept the electronic I94 (a printout Looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilnnmw2u2lhobmz/IMG_20160626_0001.pdf?dl=0)?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing (and your link is broken).

Comment: @Crazydre I suggest removing that link and posting a new one with your passport number and maybe form registration number obscured.

Comment: I altered my birthday by one year and a couple of Digits in the passport number (using Paint)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to end form I-94 now that it is only electronic?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27804/how-to-end-form-i-94-now-that-it-is-only-electronic)

Comment: @CrazydreThanks -- we now know your birthday is one of two dates and we have a great idea what your passport number is. You should just obliterate sensitive information; certainly don't change it in small ways and then announce that you did that.

Comment: Not a dupe, because I'm not asking what methods exist, but whether one specific method is possible. The ones I've been thinking of so far are: 1. Amtrak sending info to CBP (no idea whether they do that); 2. me handing in an electronic I94 printout to CBSA; 3. Me requesting a paper I94W and handing it in to CBSA; 4 (last Resort): sending electronic I94 printout+all evidence of leaving the US to the Ohio address

Comment: @Crazydre the dupe question has an official answer from US CBP: no, it's not possible (nor it is necessary).

Comment: Then how do they record the departure? Their suggestion is I should bring all evidence and have the record updated upon the next entry, which is emphatically *not* an Option for me. I want the record to be up to date Long before Setting foot in the Country again

Comment: Could you please Show me the CBP Quote so I know what you're referring to?

Comment: @Crazydre http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/27837/9009 (you can follow to the CBP website for the original)

Comment: @Crazydre dupe vote removed

Comment: Yup, like I thought. Not going to do that. If neither Amtrak (at the time of online booking) nor the CBSA will do it (though according to the CBP Website, CBSA should accept at least paper I94Ws), then I'll send the material to Ohio once in Canada. But what I'm trying to establish is which of the Options I've thought out are possible. Guess I'm going to mail CBP - hopefully I can explain this specific question well enough

Comment: @Crazydre Why is it not an option to fix it when you re-enter? It's perfectly normal for US CBP to handle this situation.

Comment: In part because when entering by air, I always use the APC kiosks, and having an overstay in their System would cause me to get an X on my receipt, thus having to stand in the slower X line

Comment: My online I94 form shows, for trips exiting by land via Canada, several times where I entered the US (normal arrival line), then a departure (otherwise blank) + normal US arrival line on the same day months later from my next trip. Never had any trouble using the APC kiosks nor Global Entry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just called the border guards at Lacolle (Canadian port of entry used by the New York-Montreal Train) and they said it's fine to hand in a printout of an electronic I94 :)

Comment: But do they do anything with it?

Comment: CBP says on their Website you can Hand in the paper version to CBSA, which means they'll send the info (why would the CBP otherwise suggest this?) I said that to the CBSA Agent and asked if the electronic form was acceptable **for the same purpose**, to which he answered yes...I guess if I take this route (air entry, Train Exit), I'll print two electronic I94 copies, Hand in one to the CBSA, and if the record isn't updated a week later (which I can check), I'll post the other copy along with all evidence of departure to the Ohio address

Answer (score 3):

I've tried it out myself a few weeks back and the answer is **yes**, they do accept the print-outs from the [DHS website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/). In fact, your exit will be recorded [even if you don't hand in your I-94](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109383/does-returning-my-i-94-at-the-canadian-border-make-any-difference-at-all) as Canada and the US share entry-and-exit information these days.